# Can I store image after registering user in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, multer, req

I have a register API. I have five parameters there -

```
name:xyz,
username:uname,
password:pwd,
profile_pic:(multipart-form-data)(imagefile)
```

In my signup api, I am expecting multipart-form-data. I am using multer to upload file, and that is uploading file succfully. In signup method, firstly I want to check whether user is already registered with the same username, if yes return the error & exit. Otherwise, upload the file in database & insert image path with all the other data. But  i can not get request body, until I upload the image file. So i am unable to check the username. req.body is not having any request variable before image uploading.

What can i do ?

Comment: let me know , you want to get user name before uploading image to check some validation ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi We have a signup function, which expects username, email, password & image. This is multipart-form-data request.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi 
While registering we have to go like this - 
1. Check whether the username is unique or not. If not unique return the response with error.
2. If username validation is passed, then upload image & put it's location in a variable.
3. Now create the user in the database with email, username, password & image.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi
The problem is -
When I hit the signup API, and check for username uniqueness(1 point above), it is unable to get req.body.username. username is always undefined. This is happening due to multipart-form-data. 

I am able to get the username after image has been uploaded. I don't no why ? I am using multer to upload image.

Answer (score 0):

when user try to signup and entered `username` `name` and `password` send these fields to the server and check and if its ok return specific result to front function to send all fields with image, or create another endpoint for checking user if it was ok, send data to signup endpoint

Comment: I want to do all these things in a single API. Why increase the number of APIs?

Comment: if you want do it in API , so you must separate data for backend ,
for example add field verify_check:true , means just check user name ,